# Magento:2.2.8 Save response in db under custom_column created in sales_order and quote tables

Tags: magento2, database, event-observer

I am using Custom Shipping API where I am getting response from API. Here I want to save this response to my order and quote table, I used event `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`
Here's code of my event under etc/frontend

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
       <event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
        <observer name="bigpost_order_controller_success_action" instance="Some\Somename\Observer\Processorder" />
    </event>
    </config>
```

Here's I am using in doing in execute function under Observer/Processorder

```
          $order_ids = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds()[0];
           $order = $this->orderRepository->get($order_ids);           
           $order_id = $order->getIncrementId();   
$job = json_decode($resut, true); //response here 
  foreach ($job as $key => $consignment) {
      $condignment = $consignment['CarrierConsignmentNumber']; //got reponse 'BP459090'
      try {
        $orderDetailData = $condignment;
        if(!empty($orderDetailData)){
        $order_id->setData('carrier_consignment_number', $orderDetailData); //tried to set data
        $order_id->save();
      }
        print("succssfully done");

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        error_log($e->getMessage());
        print("error in this");
    }
            }
```

it's not saved my data in db under sale_order table or quote table. while I created column there.

Getting error here : Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setData() on string in

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your data and also saving an order id which is a string instead of the order object.

change

```
$order_id->setData('carrier_consignment_number', $orderDetailData); //tried to set data
$order_id->save();
```

For

```
$order->setData('carrier_consignment_number', $orderDetailData); //tried to set data
$order->save();
```

Comment: Still have same error : Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setData() on string in

Comment: Check what is the content of order_ids and also make sure an actual order has been returned by $this->orderRepository->get($order_ids);

Comment: SetData always work with existing tables not with custom table for this we have to make a plugin or call model